# Why lombok not work when I add dependency by maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-tool-suite, lombok

After I add lombok dependency in pom.xml and downloaded,it not work for me, both in STS and Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 0):

### After add lombok dependency on your project, you still need to do some configuration on your IDEA.

For STS, add two configurations in STS.ini(this file located in STS root path):

- -Xbootclasspath/a:C:\Users\a243903.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.18\lombok-1.16.18.jar
- -javaagent:C:\Users\a243903.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.18\lombok-1.16.18.jar

For Intellij Idea:

- Go to File > Settings > Plugins.
- Click on Browse repositories...
- Search for Lombok Plugin.
- Click on Install plugin.
- Settings -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors, make sure check box
  Enable annotation processing
- Restart IntelliJ IDEA.